# i want to reload/refresh page after my cloned element shows

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

this is a codeigniter project

this is **view** script

v_add_transaksi.php

```
<div class="after-add-more">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Pilih Kategori Menu</label>
            <select required="required" name="id_kategori_menu" class="form-control" id="kategori">
                <option value="">- Pilih Kategori Menu -</option>
                <?php 
                foreach($kategori as $row)
                { 
                  echo '<option value="'.$row->id_kategori.'">'.$row->nama_kategori.'</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 pr-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>-Pilih Menu</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="menu" id="menu">
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 px-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div id="jumlah">
                    <label>Jumlah</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 pl-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-group remove">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-fill btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-fill add-more">Add More</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-fill" href="<?php echo base_url('admin/kategori_menu'); ?>">Kembali</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

and i put jquery script in the **homepage** that look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
//$(".add-more").load(location.href + ".add-more");
  $("body").on("click",".add-more",function(){
      var html = $(".after-add-more:first").clone(true);
      $(html).find(".remove").html("<br><a class='btn btn-danger btn-fill remove'>Remove</a>");
    $(".after-add-more").last().after(html);
  });
  $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
      $(this).parents(".after-add-more").remove();
  });
  });
</script>
```

the jquery script is for cloning my form element in the v_add_transaksi.php.

other than that, i also make my dropdown select option, chained, so when i choose 'Kategori Menu' then 'Menu' that have match **id** will show up in the second dropdown select option, here is the code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ // Ketika halaman sudah siap (sudah selesai di load)
  $("#kategori").change(function(){ // Ketika user mengganti atau memilih data provinsi
    $("#menu").hide();
    $("#jumlah").hide();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST", // Method pengiriman data bisa dengan GET atau POST
      url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/listMenu", // Isi dengan url/path file php yang dituju
      data: {id_kategori : $("#kategori").val()}, // data yang akan dikirim ke file yang dituju
      dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: function(e) {
        if(e && e.overrideMimeType) {
          e.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        }
      },
      success: function(response){ // Ketika proses pengiriman berhasil
        $("#menu").html(response.list_menu).show();
        $("#jumlah").show();
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { // Ketika ada error
        alert(xhr.status + "\n" + xhr.responseText + "\n" + thrownError); // Munculkan alert error
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

my controller admin.php

```
function listMenu() {
    $id_kategori = $this->input->post('id_kategori');
    $menu = $this->m_transaksi->get_menuByKategori($id_kategori);
    $lists = "<option value=''>- Pilih Menu -</option>";

    foreach($menu as $data){
      $lists .= "<option value='".$data->id_menu."'>".$data->nama_menu."</option>";
    }

    $callback = array('list_menu'=>$lists);
    echo json_encode($callback);
}
```

my problem is, whenever i click on 'add more' button that will make my form element cloned, the function for chained dropdown is not work, only work for the first elements only. i want the function for chained dropdown work no matter how much i cloned my form elements.

so how i can get this done? any help will be much appreciated

Comment: re render select option via ajax.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Do you meen you are fetching data from a php page asynchronously and you want to clone the result of the ajax query to the current page?

if yes there i think there is one reason you could use html element iframe so when you will append new data it will do like is reloading the page but not at all

Comment: i just need the function for dropdown chained is working on cloned elements, fetching data from the first select option is working though